# Как правильно скрывать и отображать строки таблицы с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день.

В html-коде есть таблица. Появилась потребность скриптом динамически прятать и отображать строки по некоторому признаку.

Я попробовал делать это по аналогии с тем, как обычно прятал и показывал блоки `div` - с помощью свойства `style.display`:

```
// Сначала прячу все строки
$block.children('tr').css('display', 'none')

// Потом отображаю только нужные
for (j in items) {
    let item = items[j];
    $('#'+item.id).css('display', 'block')
}
```

Строчки действительно отображаются какие нужно. Но после первого же выполнения скрипта таблицу перекашивает - у каждой строки получается разная ширина колонок и граница между колонками получается ломанной.

Answer (score 1):

Пока набирал вопрос, вспомнил, что у `style.display` бывает ещё значение `inline`. Решил посмотреть, какое значение изначально стоит у строки таблицы.

Оказалось, для строк таблицы вообще существует особое значение этого свойства - `table-row`. Таким образом, правильный способ отобразить ранее скрытую строку такой:

```
$(селектор).css('display', 'table-row')
```

С таким кодом всё заработало именно так, как я и хотел.

Comment: Казалось бы, правильный способ — через jquery методы [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) и [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), которые сохраняют значение display (`hide` сохраняет значение display в кеше jquery, затем `show` его использует).

Comment: @Дмитрий, спасибо, jquery я пока не очень хорошо знаю, вот и изобретаю велосипеды :)